# How to enumerate through multiple windows of one process c#

Tags: c#, process

I have this code that I copied from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Enumerate-top-level-9aa9d7c1):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
protected delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam); 

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
        protected static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder strText, int maxCount); 

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
        protected static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd); 

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        protected static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam); 

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        protected static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd); 

        protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam) 
        { 
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd); 
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) 
            { 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size); 
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size); 
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 
            } 
            return true; 
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

But I'm a newbie to C# and I don't exactly get the code. How do I filter e.g. that only the windows of Word are printed? (The processName of word is WINWORD)

Comment: check the "getwindowtext" .. it should contain the word word!

Comment: Use www.pinvoke.net.  You can get the process name from the handle.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindow